# Calling functions on socket message (socket.io/node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, socket.io

When I start a new instance of GameServer, it sets up the socket and listeners as follows.

```
var GameServer = function() {
    this.player = new Player();
    var that = this;

    // Setup sockets and listeners
    var socket = io.listen(8000);
    socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
        client.on('message', that.onSocketMessage);
        client.on('disconnect', that.onSocketDisconnect);
    });
}
```

I then have two prototypes GameServer.prototype.onSocketMessage & onSocketDisconnect.

I have two problems with the current code:

1. Using that = this and the closure? function. Looks ugly.
2. When onSocketMessage is called, the idea is it works out what the message is then calls another function within GameServer. Only this isn't possible as now this belongs to the socket.io system. See below:

...

```
function onSocketMessage() {
    this.player.move();
}
```

this.player is no longer available as this. is no longer part of GameServer.

Should my socket setup and message passing be handled outside of GameServer function and prototypes?

Or how else could I resolve this?

Cheers

**EDIT**

Ok so I have tried this and it works but looks pretty ugly I think:

```
var socket = io.listen(8000);
socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.on('message', function (data) {
        that.onSocketMessage(this, that, data);
    });
    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        that.onSocketDisconnect(this, that);
    });
});
```

Can it be improved upon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things that may help. Thing the first:

You can modify a function's vision of `this` using [the `bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.on('message', this.onSocketMessage);
    client.on('disconnect', this.onSocketDisconnect);
}.bind(this));
```

Notice the call to `bind(this)` at the end of the function; this instructs JavaScript to create a closure for you, making whatever `this` is outside the function, `this` inside the function. (If you wanted to make `this` inside the function, say, `MySomething`, you could just as easily call `bind(MySomething)`, though `bind(this)` is the most common use).

Thing the second:

You can store data in a Socket.IO socket. So, for example, if one socket is always associated with a player, you can do

```
socket.set('player', player, function() {
  // callback is called when variable is successfully stored
  console.log('player has been stored');
});

// and later

socket.get('player', function(err, player) {
  // callback is called either with an error set or the value you requested
  player.move();
});
```

The `get` and `set` methods take callbacks because the Socket.IO data store can be set to something other than an in-memory store; for example, Redis.

Comment: The bind option works perfectly. Funnily enough I had already tried bind but I had implemented it incorrectly and it didn't work. Now I can see why! Question though: 'client.on('message', this.onSocketMessage.bind(this));' When that message is received, normally within onSocketMessage, you would have this.id available (which would be the client/sockets id) and (data) passed into your function. Data is still passed, but I no longer have any access to this.id. How would I get that passed in as well?

Comment: You cannot; that's why `bind` is really only useful for your first issue. For your second issue, I would work on getting the `player` into the method some other way.